# What is the best approach to solve sliding statue puzzles in Super Lucky's Tale?

Tags: nintendo-switch, super-luckys-tale

I managed to get through the first few sliding statue puzzles through trial and error, but the later puzzles are much harder. I often get to a point where all of the statues are in the right place but one. But then I need to undo all of the work I did before as some statues are needed to get the last one in place. Do these puzzles essentially reduce to another type of classic puzzle which I can find strategies online for? Is there a way to work out which order to solve the statues in?

When searching Google for this, all I can find is readymade solutions to each puzzle. I don't want this, I want to solve them myself, but just not sure how to go about it.

PS: I'm playing the Nintendo Switch version ("New" Super Lucky's Tale); I know there are differences with this version, but I think this particular question would apply to any of the versions.